# Python how to check if a string contains a word

Tags: python, python-2.7

i am trying to check if str1 exist in str2

```
def string_contains(str1,str2):
    return bool (str1 in str2)

print (string_contains("llo","hello how are you"))
# expected false but return value is true
# the possible true for s1 is hello or hello how or hello how are
# hello how are you
```

Comment: Have you done any research about how `in` works with strings? Any at all?

Comment: @J.J.Hakala - Read this question more carefully. It's not a duplicate.

Comment: ...but `"llo"` is in str2. Its the last 3 letters in `"hello"`. Can you be more speicific in your requirements? The example hints that the match must be at the start of str2 and must match on word boundaries... correct?

Comment: What about "how are you" or "you"? Should they also return `True`?

Comment: `str1 in str2.split()` I guess is what you want ...

Comment: From your description, `str2.startswith(str1)` is sufficient. But it would match "Hello how ar" for instance.

Answer (score 1):

This should work - it will ensure only whole words are matched, and sentences must match from the start.

```
def string_contains(str1,str2):
    lst1 = str1.split(' ')
    lst2 = str2.split(' ')

    if len(lst1) <= len(lst2):
        return lst1 == lst2[:len(lst1)]

    return False

print (string_contains("llo", "hello how are you"))  # False
print (string_contains("hello", "hello how are you"))  # True
print (string_contains("hello how", "hello how are you"))  # True
print (string_contains("hello how a", "hello how are you"))  # False
```

Comment: You can use a `first_idx = lst2.index(lst1[0])` to get answers that don't match from the start. It can raise an exception that needs to be treated if there's no match between the list.

Answer (score 0):

I like using regular expression module `re`.

Code:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('\sllo\s')  # add another parameter `re.I` for case insensitive
match = pattern.search('hello how are you')
if match:
    return True
else:
    return False
```